# Convert a long character field to numeric, NOT scientific notation (SAS)

Tags: format, sas

I need to join two tables - one table has householdid which is CHAR30, which appears to have center alignment and the other householdid as numeric 20.  I need to convert to the numeric 20  but when I do that it appears truncated, perhaps because of the strange alignment (not all of the 30 positions are actually needed).

When I try to keep the full 30 positions as a numeric I instead get a conversion to scientific notation so of course this will not work as a key id for later operations.

Comment: If you're dealing with large numbers, I'd recommend keeping your ID as CHAR30 instead so you can avoid any possible precision errors.  In general ID fields should be chars not numeric - they don't have value.

Comment: Yes....ID makes no sense as numeric, but that's how it is in numerous tables I work with.  I need to find a workaround or convert everything to character that touches it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the number is converted properly, it doesn't matter what format it has.  A format just tells SAS how to show you the number.  Behind the scenes, it is just a DOUBLE.

1.0 = 1 = 1e0

Now if you have converted to a number and cannot get a join, then look at the `informat` you used to read it in.

try

```
num_id = input(strip(char_id),best32.);
```

Strip removes leading and trailing blanks.  The `BEST32. INFORMAT` tries its "best" to read the number up to 32 characters in length.

Comment: Note that `BEST` is a format.  If you use `BEST32.` as an informat you get the same result as using `32.` or `F32.`.

Comment: Okay, so it's a numeric 8. but both the format and informat are 20.  How does that figure in this?

Comment: .and...when joining does the informat have to be the same length in both tables?

Comment: Numeric 8 just says it is an 8 byte number.  The join is happening on the numbers.  The formats do not matter -- they only tell SAS how to show your squishy grey matter computer the number.  If there is not a successful join, then there was an issue converting your string to numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store a 20 digit number as a numeric in SAS.  SAS stores all numbers as 8 byte floating point and so does not have enough bits to represent that many digits uniquely.  You can ask SAS what is the largest integer it can represent exactly by using the `CONSTANT()` function.

```
1    data _null_;
2      x=constant('EXACTINT',8);
3      put x = comma32. ;
4    run;

x=9,007,199,254,740,992
```

Read and store your 20 and 30 digit strings as character variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `bestd32.` format. Tends to work out pretty well for long key variables. Depending on the length of the variable, you can change `32` to whichever length you need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments under the original question, the only thing you can do is convert all ID fields to strings, and use the strings to do the joins.  @Reeza suggested this in one of the comments but it should have been posted as an answer.

I assume you are pulling this information out of another database/system that allows for greater numeric precision then SAS does.  If you don't convert the values to strings **when they are read into SAS**, then you run the risk of losing precision.

If you lose precision, the ID in SAS is likely to become very slightly different to the ID in the original system, which can cause problems when searching the original system for an ID obtained from SAS.

Be sure you don't read the numbers into SAS as numeric, then convert to string.  If you do it this way you are still losing precision as soon as the numbers are stored in SAS as numeric variables.